# How do I deal with my roommates wanting a lower tier of internet service?

Tags: relationships, roommates, approach, housemates

I live with 2 roommates and we are students. We are really good friends, we have each other's back but you know, there are going to be problems too. I study Computer science, the other roommates study Mechanical engineering and Physological counseling and guidance.

We are going to set up internet in our new apartment and we have a disagreement about that. My roommates do not care about the internet that much, they just surf on Instagram and Whatsapp. I, on the other hand, watch programming videos on YouTube all day, there are always software updates, and so on.

They think it is a waste of money to pay money for internet. That's why they want 30 GB limited internet, but I know it would last for maximum 1 week. It is like they stand against me together. What do I do? How do I explain my side to them?

Comment: Is there anything that prevents you from covering the extra-cost for an unlimited connection yourself?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, money.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most things in life are a compromise. It sounds like your internet usage requirements are greater than theirs, so seen from their perspective it would be wasteful to pay for a higher capacity/speed service than they need, just to accommodate you.

What I would suggest is, you find the difference in price between the service they would be happy with, and the one you want, and offer to pay the difference yourself. For example, if their service would cost $30 and yours $40, you split the $30 three ways ($10 each) and you pay the extra $10 for the better one. This would seem reasonable as you are the one who will benefit most from the extra service.

Admittedly they make also get to take advantage of the better service, but that is something you may have to accept as a consequence of you getting the outcome you want. Convincing them to pay equally for something they don't feel is a necessity seems a touch unreasonable in my view.

Comment: Wow, that's such an great idea. Right, they say they don't need it, but I'm 100% sure that they will take advantage of it. It's best to find a close price which I think we all will be happy, thanks a lot.

Comment: Since OP is a technical student he might be able to set up their router to only give full bandwidth to his devices as compensation

Comment: @Misamoto of course I can limit speed but I don't think it would be good idea

Comment: You can first suggest split the extra $10 like 1 + 1 + 8 (you) before offering cover the full cost, so they only have a 10% increase for a full bandwidth. Also you can mention getting Netflix would need the extra bandwidth if that is something everyone will want to get in a future.